# The position where the word wrapped in a Label in Visual C#

Tags: c#, printing, position, label

I use:

```
label1.MaximumSize = new Size(100,0);
label1.AutoSize = true;
```

to autowrap the label. And use

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text,new SolidBrush(Color.Black),10,10);
```

to print the label.

But now comes the problem: The DrawString only take label1.Text as "pure string". It does not include any wrappings. So my result looks like

```
This is a printing test!
```

instead of:

```
This is a printing
test!
```

which is what it should be. Is there any way that I can know where the text is wrapped (after "printing" in this case) so I can add `\n` to it in order to get the correct printing result?

Or perhaps there are better ways to do it other than add a `\n` to it?

The numbers in the example are just examples. They are *not* the correct measurement by any means.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics.MeasureString should give you the width of your string. You can then break it apart when it reaches your max, perhaps using a StringBuilder so you can get it as you go.

```
        string text = "This is a printing test!";
        Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var c in text.ToArray())
            {
                var l = g.MeasureString(sb.Append(c).ToString(), stringFont);
                if (l.Width >= 100)
                {
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"String: {sb.ToString()} Length: {l.Width.ToString()}");
            }
        }
```

Update:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = "This is a printing test!";
        var f = new Font("Arial", 16);
        var w = 100d;
        Console.WriteLine(BreakIntoLines(s, w, f));
    }
    public static string BreakIntoLines(string s, double w, Font f)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var pw = 0d;
            foreach (var c in s.ToArray())
            {
                var lw = Math.Floor(g.MeasureString(sb.Append(c).ToString(), f).Width / w);
                if (lw != pw)
                {
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    pw = lw;
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Update (split by word, not character):

```
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            var words = s.Split(' ');
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var pw = 0d;
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                var lw = Math.Floor(g.MeasureString($"{sb.ToString()} {word}", f).Width / w);
                if (lw != pw)
                {
                    sb.Append($"{Environment.NewLine}{word} ");
                    pw = lw;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append($"{word} ");
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...
But this is... painstaking!!! >"<
Isn't there any better way!?

Comment: There's no way to infer what the size of a string will be without knowing the width of each letter and what font you're going to use to display it. You can guess, but you'll always be wrong. This is quick code as a POC. I'm sure it could be cleaned up. See updated code.

Comment: OK... say... would it be better if I append "a word at a time"!? So it won't be cut off in the middle of a word!?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Updating.

Answer (score 0):

I found one thing amazing!

You can use DrawString to print the text into a Rectangle, than it will autowrap it for you!

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text,label1.Font,new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
new Rectangle(label1.Left,label1.Top,label1.Width,label1.Height));
```